# What courses should one take for working towards Astronomy from an AI / Data Analysis perspective?

Tags: galaxy, astrophysics, cosmology, data-analysis, planetary-science

Note:- This is a suggestions seeking question

As a prospective student about to embark on pursuing the MEngg. in Applied AI program, I am eager to align my education with my passion for Astronomy. I would appreciate guidance on selecting subjects that would enable me to contribute to advanced research in exploring galaxies, stars, and other celestial phenomena. How can I tailor my coursework to best support my aspirations in merging AI and Astronomy for groundbreaking discoveries?

I'm really looking forward to make the best use of AI by applying it in my passion, Astronomy. Would appreciate if someone could share their preferred course list from below if you were to make this decision. Following is the course sequence screenshot for your reference. Thanks
[image: Applied AI courses]

2 Electives can be taken from any department. Following is a list from the Space Engineering program. This is more of an Aerospace level program, but what would be more relevant:-

[image: Space Engineering program]